# why do I have this error? Error 1822: Failed to Add foreign key constraint Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql

**I have the following code:**

```
CREATE DATABASE Sena;
Use Sena;


-- Tabla de Roles
CREATE TABLE Roles (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    rol VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE
);

-- Insertar roles permitidos
INSERT INTO Roles (rol) VALUES ('Aprendiz'), ('Instructor'), ('Funcionario'), ('Director'), ('Visitante');

-- Tabla de Aprendices
CREATE TABLE Aprendices (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    numero_ficha INT,
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_aprendices_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id)
);

-- Tabla de Instructores
CREATE TABLE Instructores (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    coordinacion VARCHAR(100),
    cursos_asignados TEXT,
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_instructores_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id)
);

-- Tabla de Funcionarios
CREATE TABLE Funcionarios (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    coordinacion VARCHAR(100),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_funcionarios_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id)
);

-- Tabla de Directores
CREATE TABLE Directores (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    privilegios VARCHAR(255),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_directores_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id)
);

-- Tabla de Visitantes
CREATE TABLE Visitantes (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    empresa_procedencia VARCHAR(100),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_visitantes_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id)
);

-- Tabla de Pertenencias
CREATE TABLE Pertenencias (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    descripcion VARCHAR(255),
    serial VARCHAR(50),
    usuario_id INT,
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_aprendiz FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Aprendices(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_instructor FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Instructores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_funcionarios FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Funcionarios(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_director FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Directores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_visitantes FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Visitantes(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- Tabla de Transporte
CREATE TABLE Transporte (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    placa VARCHAR(20),
    marca VARCHAR(50),
    color VARCHAR(50),
    tipo VARCHAR(50),
    usuario_id INT,
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_transporte_aprendiz FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Aprendices(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_transporte_instructor FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Instructores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_transporte_funcionario FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Funcionarios(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_transporte_director FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Directores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_transporte_visitante FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Visitantes(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- Tabla de Ingreso
CREATE TABLE Ingreso (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    usuario_id INT,
    rol_id INT,
    fecha DATE,
    hora_ingreso TIME,
    descripcion_motivo VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_aprendiz FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Aprendices(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_instructor FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Instructores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_funcionario FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Funcionarios(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_director FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Directores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_visitante FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Visitantes(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- Tabla de Salida
CREATE TABLE Salida (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    usuario_id INT,
    rol_id INT,
    ingreso_id INT,
    hora_salida TIME,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_aprendiz FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Aprendices(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_instructor FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Instructores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_funcionario FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Funcionarios(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_director FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Directores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_visitante FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Visitantes(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_ingreso FOREIGN KEY (ingreso_id) REFERENCES Ingreso(id)
);
```

**and I get the following error:**

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_pertenencias_aprendiz' in the referenced table 'aprendices' 0.016 sec

**I have tried to make several changes and but I cannot fix this error, who can help me correct this error.**

Comment: that code is not for sql server it has no option auto_increment see https://www.atlassian.com/data/admin/how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simultaneously have the same pair of columns `(usuario_id, rol_id)` reference columns in different tables.

If you are saying it sometimes refers to a 'director' and sometimes to an 'instructor', that is a bad schema design.  Please describe your schema (in words) so we can help untangle the mess.

Answer (score 0):

You asked why do you get this error.

The `Aprendices` table includes columns `id` and `rol_id`, but the primary key is the single column `id` alone.

```
CREATE TABLE Aprendices (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
    rol_id INT
);
```

The `Pertenencias` table has a foreign key that references the pair of columns in `Aprendices`.

```
CREATE TABLE Pertenencias (
    ...
    usuario_id INT,
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_aprendiz FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) 
      REFERENCES Aprendices(id, rol_id)
    ...
);
```

When a foreign key column a pair of columns, the referenced table must have a two-column primary key or unique key. Your `Aprendices` table only has a single-column primary key. There is no key in that table that you can be referenced by a two-column foreign key.

That's why the error says, *"Missing index for constraint 'fk_pertenencias_aprendiz' in the referenced table 'aprendices'"* — because no suitable index (aka key) exists in the referenced table.

To solve this, you must do either one of the following:

- Change the foreign key in `Pertenencias` to be a single column, referencing the single-column primary key of `Aprendices`.
- Define a two-column primary key or unique key in `Aprendices`, with both columns referenced by the foreign key.

Answer (score -1):

> I have tried to make several changes and but I cannot fix this error,
> who can help me correct this error

Based on error message try to create missing index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON Aprendices (id, rol_id);
```

This index doesn't make sense since there is unique one for primary key and only needed for foreign key.

Comment: Since `id` is already `UNIQUE` (because of being the `PRIMARY KEY`), adding `UNIQUE(id, ...)` will not be of any use.